# Connecting to Mysql on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am relatively new LAMP dev who is trying to learn Linux primarily through AWS. I have a live Elastic Beanstalk instance up and running. I did a yum install of the following packages:

```
mysql55.x86_64 mysql55-bench.x86_64 mysql55-common.x86_64 mysql55-devel.x86_64 mysql55-libs.x86_64 mysql55-server.x86_64 mysql55-test.x86_64
```

Which all seemed to install fine ... then typed ...

```
mysql -V
```

which gets me

```
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

... which confirms mysql is installed ... but then when I type ...

```
mysql -u ec2-user -p
Enter password: /*leaving blank*/
```

I get ...

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Now the thing is I am ssh-ing into this server with a Security Group key pair I created in AWS Console. So the key is authenticating me (from the .ppk file) when I log into the box as ec2-user. That IS my "root" user as far as I know, there is no password, but I may be mistaken.

So, basically I don't understand the basics of how to begin using MySQL in a linux environment. I've only really used PHPMyAdmin and the MySQL command line from WAMP until now.

Can somebody help me with where I'm getting my wires crossed here?

Comment: I should add, though it might be obvious, but I've already ssh'd into the ec2 instance and have the linux file system at my disposal. I just don't know enough about linux yet.

Comment: would like to add that typing: mysql -V ... gets me
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1 ... which confirms mysql is installed but typing mysql -u root -p ... gets me: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: And since I'm sshing into the server with my keypair I'm not using a password for the root user. Could THAT be the issue ... ????

Comment: my /etc/init.d/ doesn't contain anything mysql* related ... no such file or directory

Comment: Contents of my etc/my.cnf is: 
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 but the mysql.sock doesn't exists either

Comment: OK, I guess mysql-server never got installed when I did the yum install on so many packages all at once ... I have mysqld in my etc/init.d now ... 

That should solve it!

Comment: yea...u didnot start ur server yet....

Answer (score 15):

Whoa. Hold up. Before you do anything else, stop and spin up your mysql machine outside of beanstalk, or use [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/). Beanstalk is designed to autoscale the web tier of your application, not hold your database. The moment it scales your application up, that new machine won't have your data. The moment it scales back down, it might remove your database machine. If that instance ends up on retired or corrupt hardware, beanstalk will replace it.

[Give the Beanstalk architectural overview a read.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html) Note the diagram. Your database layer exists outside the beanstalk environment, not in it.

[image: In this diagram the beanstalk environment is delineated by the broken yellow line.]

Comment: That's right Chris, but is there a good alternative to setup a mysql db outside of Auto Scaling Group web apps, in way that all web apps can connect with it? Pretty much like replace the DB in the diagram above with a mysql running on a EBS. Or even maybe, setup a mysql in the first EC2 instance and never let it shutdown?

Comment: @DanielDener: Absolutely. Just create one or many MySQL dbs on their own instances, drop them in a common security group, and make sure the beanstalk SecurityGroup can reach it on port 3306. All that matters is keeping the DB off the AutoScaling group's members.

Comment: @Chistopher Thanks! Although looking over some features of RDS, I decided to give it a try, starting with the _micro_ instance. Hopefully a good cache (Varnish) within each Web App server and CloudFront will less stress to the RDS.