# How does ElasticBeanStalk deploy your application version to instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently using AWS ElasticBeanStalk and I was curious as to how (as in internally) it knows that when you fire up an instance (or it automatically does with scaling), to unpack the zip I uploaded as a version? Is there some enviroment setting that looks up my zip in my S3 bucket and then unpacks automatically for every instance running in that environment?

If so, could this be used to automate a task such as run an SQL query on boot-up (instance deployment) too? Are these automated tasks changeable or viewable at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how beanstalk knows which version to download and unpack, but running a task on start-up is trivial. Check out `cloud-init`, a [tool written by Ubuntu that's now packaged in Amazon Linux.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) It allows you to pass arbitrary shell scripts into the UserData section of the instance configuration, and those shell scripts will run on startup.

[It's a great way to bootstrap instances on startup,](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-waitcondition-article.html) which avoids the soul-sucking misery of managing AMIs.

A quick (possibly non-applicable) warning: If you're running a SQL query on a database that lives on the beanstalk AMI, you're pretty much guaranteed to lose your database at some point. Those machines are designed to be entirely transient. Do not put databases on them. [See this answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11471408/877115)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that! We're using RDS for our SQL solution, so this isn't a problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal seems to be to run custom configuration tasks, the answer is yes, there is a way to do that. You can define custom actions in an .ebextensions file packaged with your app. For example, you can configure a command to run every time a new machine is deployed:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands