# steps to deploy war and install mysql on the ec2 instance of aws

Tags: mysql, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have created my aws account and I am able to acces the ec2 instance through putty.
So now how to deploy war on this instance and install mysql which the war will access?
Please can anyone gives me the steps about how to go with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [ElasticBeanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) a look, but pay close attention to its [architectural overview.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11471408/877115) Outlining all the steps required to get your application running would be difficult without considerably more information and lots and lots of time, but those resources should get you much closer. If you have specific questions that you can't find answers to (many of which are answered on this or another SE site), feel free to ask, but check out the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for tips on constructing questions well.